# how to calculate cumulative insect day using r?

Tags: r

Hi I need to calculate the cumulative insect day for some of my experiment. This is what my data frame looks like

```
Rep trt      date BLB
1    I   1 7/12/2017   3
2    I   2 7/12/2017   2
3    I   3 7/12/2017   4
4    I   4 7/12/2017   0
5   II   1 7/12/2017   1
6   II   2 7/12/2017   2
7   II   3 7/12/2017   2
8   II   4 7/12/2017   1
9  III   1 7/12/2017   3
10 III   2 7/12/2017   2
11 III   3 7/12/2017   1
12 III   4 7/12/2017   1
13  IV   1 7/12/2017   0
14  IV   2 7/12/2017   3
15  IV   3 7/12/2017   3
16  IV   4 7/12/2017   0
17   I   1 7/20/2017  12
18   I   2 7/20/2017   6
19   I   3 7/20/2017   7
20   I   4 7/20/2017  18
21  II   1 7/20/2017  17
22  II   2 7/20/2017  11
23  II   3 7/20/2017  25
24  II   4 7/20/2017  17
25 III   1 7/20/2017  18
26 III   2 7/20/2017   6
27 III   3 7/20/2017  48
28 III   4 7/20/2017  13
29  IV   1 7/20/2017   7
30  IV   2 7/20/2017  22
31  IV   3 7/20/2017  18
32  IV   4 7/20/2017  11
33   I   1 7/27/2017   1
34   I   2 7/27/2017   3
35   I   3 7/27/2017   4
36   I   4 7/27/2017   0
37  II   1 7/27/2017   1
38  II   2 7/27/2017   0
39  II   3 7/27/2017   1
40  II   4 7/27/2017   0
41 III   1 7/27/2017   1
42 III   2 7/27/2017   1
43 III   3 7/27/2017   0
44 III   4 7/27/2017   0
45  IV   1 7/27/2017   1
46  IV   2 7/27/2017   0
47  IV   3 7/27/2017   1
48  IV   4 7/27/2017   2
49   I   1  8/2/2017   0
50   I   2  8/2/2017   0
51   I   3  8/2/2017   1
52   I   4  8/2/2017   0
53  II   1  8/2/2017   0
54  II   2  8/2/2017   0
55  II   3  8/2/2017   0
56  II   4  8/2/2017   0
57 III   1  8/2/2017   1
58 III   2  8/2/2017   0
59 III   3  8/2/2017   0
60 III   4  8/2/2017   0
61  IV   1  8/2/2017   0
62  IV   2  8/2/2017   0
63  IV   3  8/2/2017   0
64  IV   4  8/2/2017   2
```

Structure would be:

```
    data.frame':    64 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Rep : Factor w/ 4 levels "I","II","III",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ trt : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ date: Factor w/ 4 levels "7/12/2017","7/20/2017",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ BLB : int  3 2 4 0 1 2 2 1 3 2 ...
```

To do it, I need calculate the average of insect for each combination of date for the different treatment. for example I have to calculate the every between date 7/12 and 7/20 for each treatment. Then I need to calculate the average between date 7/20 and 7/27, etc. Does anyone knows how to do this using r software? I really appreciate the help!!

Comment: So are you treating 7/12 and 7/20 as one group? and 7/20 and 7/27 another?

Comment: Yes I am treating each combination of two date as one group!!

Comment: You can use `dput(dataframe)` next time?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you expect as output. Could you demonstrate for 7/12 through 7/20 and 7/20 through 7/27?

Comment: and BLB is "insect"?

Comment: I want to do the mean of bean leaf beetle (BLB) for the pairs of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create data (would be nice if you provided dput(data)...):

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(Rep = rep(c("I","II","III","IV"), each = 4, times = 4),
                trt = as.factor(rep(1:4, times = 16)),
                date = as.Date(rep(c("7/12/2017", "7/20/2017", "7/27/2017", "8/2/2017"), each = 16),
                               format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                BLB = sample(0:50, 64, replace = TRUE))

> str(df)
'data.frame':   64 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Rep : Factor w/ 4 levels "I","II","III",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ trt : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ date: Date, format: "2017-07-12" "2017-07-12" "2017-07-12" ...
 $ BLB : int  14 40 20 45 47 2 26 45 28 23 ...
```

Simple subsetting and aggregation:

```
# Create subset for each date group
date_group1 = subset(df, df$date %in% c(as.Date("2017-07-12"),
                                        as.Date("2017-07-20")))
date_group2 = subset(df, df$date %in% c(as.Date("2017-07-20"),
                                        as.Date("2017-07-27")))
date_group3 = subset(df, df$date %in% c(as.Date("2017-07-27"),
                                        as.Date("2017-08-02")))

# Aggregate by treatment in each date_group
aggregate(BLB ~ trt, data = date_group1, mean)
aggregate(BLB ~ trt, data = date_group2, mean)
aggregate(BLB ~ trt, data = date_group3, mean)

# > aggregate(BLB ~ trt, data = date_group1, mean)
#   trt    BLB
# 1   1 28.375
# 2   2 21.750
# 3   3 27.875
# 4   4 41.500
# > aggregate(BLB ~ trt, data = date_group2, mean)
#   trt    BLB
# 1   1 23.875
# 2   2 19.875
# 3   3 21.625
# 4   4 31.250
# > aggregate(BLB ~ trt, data = date_group3, mean)
#   trt    BLB
# 1   1 22.375
# 2   2 21.250
# 3   3 17.875
# 4   4 17.500
```

Comment: @Obiratanea If you think this answers your question. Please accept it so others can see.

Comment: @Obiratanea "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.": https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some date combination group @useR

There are 
(2017-07-12, 2017-07-27),
(2017-07-12, 2017-08-02),
(2017-07-20, 2017-08-02) also.

Comment: OP mentioned "between date 7/12 and 7/20" and "between date 7/20 and 7/27". So I assumed he only wanted consecutive pairs, since from 2017-07-12 to 2017-07-27 would include 2017-07-20 for example.